# Is there any way to select all the content of CKEditor 5 by code?

Tags: ckeditor, ckeditor5

I want to select all content of the editor and execute a command on it in CKEditor 5.

Is it possible?

Comment: Borderline too broad. Isn't something like `setTo` working like it should? https://docs.ckeditor.com/ckeditor5/latest/api/module_engine_model_selection-Selection.html

Comment: What you linked to is the detached selection instance. The [`DocumentSelection`](https://docs.ckeditor.com/ckeditor5/latest/api/module_engine_model_documentselection-DocumentSelection.html) can only be changed by using the [writer](https://docs.ckeditor.com/ckeditor5/latest/api/module_engine_model_writer-Writer.html). Read more in https://docs.ckeditor.com/ckeditor5/latest/framework/guides/architecture/editing-engine.html#positions-ranges-and-selections

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The shortest code which will get you there is this:

```
const root = doc.getRoot();

editor.model.change( writer => {
    writer.setSelection( root, 'in' );

    // Execute command in the same change() block to have just one undo step.
    editor.execute( 'someCommand' );
} );
```

It uses the model writer's [`setSelection()`](https://docs.ckeditor.com/ckeditor5/latest/api/module_engine_model_writer-Writer.html#function-setSelection).

However, it's not entirely correct. The above code tries to make the following selection:

```
<$root>[<paragraph>X</paragraph><paragraph>Y</paragraph>]</$root>
```

While what you want to have is this:

```
<$root><paragraph>[X</paragraph><paragraph>Y]</paragraph></$root>
```

That's because the selection should always stick to a text (or [object elements](https://docs.ckeditor.com/ckeditor5/latest/api/module_engine_model_schema-Schema.html#function-isObject)).

Fortunately, since version 11.0.0 CKEditor 5 validates the selection's position and so it will be automatically moved to the correct place.

Prior to v11.0.0 or if you want to be really correct, you need to implement a bit longer solution which [finds the right selection positions](https://docs.ckeditor.com/ckeditor5/latest/api/module_engine_model_schema-Schema.html#function-getNearestSelectionRange) at the beginning and at the end of the content:

```
import Range from '@ckeditor/ckeditor5-engine/src/model/range';

const doc = editor.model.document;
const root = doc.getRoot();

editor.model.change( writer => {
    const range = Range.createIn( root );

    const startRange = editor.model.schema.getNearestSelectionRange( range.start );
    const endRange = editor.model.schema.getNearestSelectionRange( range.end );

    writer.setSelection( new Range( startRange.start, endRange.end ) );

    // Execute command in the same change() block to have just one undo step.
    editor.execute( 'someCommand' );
} );
```

Comment: @Reinmer : Is it possible to call it from outside editor's code? I have editor instance but model is not defined on it ?

Comment: I am using Alpha version not beta.

Comment: Yep, this API has changed dramatically in 1.0.0-beta. And the first solution (the slightly flawed one) can be done from outside of the editor's code. The latter requires `Range` as we didn't yet add `create*()` methods in `editor.model`.

Comment: Any way to doit in alpha version ?

Comment: Without having access to `Range`? No. In the alpha version even the smallest change required importing the `Range`.

Comment: You need to `import Range from '@ckeditor/ckeditor5-engine/src/model/range'`.

Comment: But sinve v11.0.0 you can use the first code sample in this answer. You don't need to use those `getNearestSelectionRange()` methods.

Comment: FYI: Since CKEditor 5 v19.0.0 there's a [Select All plugin](https://ckeditor.com/docs/ckeditor5/latest/features/select-all.html) that does something similar when you call `editor.execute( 'selectAll' );`.